# GPS almanac with Delphi

Tags: delphi, gps, coordinates

I need use Delphi to create an application about GPS almanac. Something like this:

[image]

Where can I download the data and read them? (to plot them). 
My user must be select a day and a latitude/longitude position, then I need plot the GPS availability for next 7 days. Where I can download this information and read them with delphi?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the method `GET` from a `TIdHTTP` and get files from: http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?Do=gpsArchives

For example:

```
IdHTTP.Get('http://www.navcen.uscg.gov/?Do=gpsArchives&path=almanacs&year=2012&file=8101&type=almanacContent--almanacId&name=001.ALM', ms);
```

Comment: Any idea about as read this data? I see this is a text plain file but how can I plot these data? Thanks

Comment: This is another question... like @WoutervanNifterick said: Starts with accepting your already asked questions, and then we'll see...

Comment: You need to parse it... you can for example load the downloaded data in a `stringlist` and then extract the data you need

Comment: The problem is: I don't know which data I need. I'm not a GPS expert but I need plot the GPS availability for next 7 days (to choose the best day) with this input: coordinates point. time zone and start day. Any idea?

Comment: No idea... you should ask a GPS question without Delphi related stuff to try having an answer from a GPS expert...